# Jenkins | Not Able to Use Injected Environment Variables in Execute Shell section

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I am injecting a variable say foo in Jenkins using "Inject Environment Variables". In properties content I've added this line `foo="bar"`

The value that I provide while running the job `abc` and it gets changed to `bar` by injecting it.

In "Execute Shell" section I have written: `echo $foo`

This gives result `abc` instead of `xyz`

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you are providing the same variable value at the time of run (say by passing it as a string parameter), it is supposed to overwrite the one specified as properties content.

Comment: The value is being overwritten which is evident from the fact that when I use the value in maven goal specified in the job, it takes the updated value.